# paypal payment integration to my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I see this demo example and I am a little bit confused.
In this demo website by paypal you can pay by visa enter digits and cvc code without redirecting to paypal.
https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/navigation?merchant=bigbox&page=merchantCreditCard

Before that I thought that you can only redirect user to paypal and make him enter his card numbers there(so he know he can trust paypal and not some website created 2 weeks ago))
So If I do this direct paypament with inputing visa card number on my website will I need to pass some verification?

Is it dificult to integrate it?